# Is My Router Blocking SMB 445?

Tags: router, smb

I am trying to [mount an Azure File Share](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) from my Ubuntu 18.10 laptop (kernel 4.18.0-15-generic).

```
sudo mount -t cifs //12345xyz.file.core.windows.net/username-company-com-100120003abcd4e5 /mnt/MyAzureFileShare -o vers=3.0,username=12345xyz,password=12345,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
```

But I get the error:

```
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
```

When I run a traceroute on port 445 it stops at the router (ASUS RT-N12 D1)

```
sudo traceroute -T -O info -p 445 12345xyz.file.core.windows.net
traceroute to 12345xyz.file.core.windows.net (13.85.88.66), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router.asus.com (192.168.1.1)  2.831 ms  2.751 ms  2.735 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

According to the router admin page the firewall is on but there are no rules listed filtering anything.

What else can I do to see if it is the router blocking the port?

Comment: What OS are you using?  What version of SMB are you using?  Instead of submitting a comment, edit your question, to include this vital information.

Comment: It’s much more likely your ISP is doing this.

Comment: I contacted the ISP and they said that they don't block any ports.

Comment: Are yoy sure that Azure has no firewalls in lace. Also, shoudlnt your share name be enquoted (or otherwise escaped) so the //  at the beginning and / are correctly interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

To mount the Azure File Share to the other systems, you can just find the mount command in the Azure portal, File Share **connect**.

For example, mount the file share to a Ubuntu system, find the command:

[image]

And then just copy and execute the command in the Ubuntu system with your mount point, and the result like this:

[image]

Of curse, you need to make sure the port 445 opened and SMB is in the right version.

Comment: But that's exactly what OP is already doing.

Comment: @grawity I know that and it just tells it could work. So there is something wrong with his job.

Comment: This is useful in an unrelated way in that the link to the command to copy and paste is not documented in the help pages. However, this answer doesn't answer the question about the port being blocked.

Comment: @opticyclic I also cannot traceroute the address while I can mount it. For the block, you can check your local firewall. As the error shows, I think you should check if there is something wrong with your nic. Also a question, what type is your Linux system?

Comment: I updated the question to add that I am using Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Can you test the mount command using, say, a 4G connection to definitely rule out it being your router/ISP?